# Return an object with list of nodes and their relationships in a subgraph

Tags: memgraphdb

I want to return an object with list of nodes and their relationships in a subgraph (`BFS` with max 2 hops) and finished with something like this:

```
MATCH path=(n {id: 2})-[r *BFS ..2]->(m)
UNWIND nodes(path) AS subgraphNode
UNWIND relationships(path) as subgraphRel
RETURN {
  nodes: collect(DISTINCT subgraphNode),
  relationships: collect(DISTINCT subgraphRel)
}
```

I would like to add some sort of pagination to the response (so combination of `SKIP` and `LIMIT`). Since both lists are of different length the idea is to limit the number of relationships returned and return only nodes that are "part" of this limited set of relationships. Any tips? I thought about collecting relationships first with `SKIP` and `LIMIT` and then somehow filter nodes that are either start node or end node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would a query like this one possibly solve your issue?

```
MATCH path=(n {id: 2})-[r *BFS ..2]->(m)
WITH relationships(path) AS subgraphRels
LIMIT 10 // Set your desired LIMIT value
WITH collect(subgraphRels) AS limitedRels
UNWIND limitedRels AS subgraphRel
WITH startNode(subgraphRel[0]) AS startNode, endNode(subgraphRel[0]) AS endNode, limitedRels
WITH startNode, endNode, limitedRels
WITH collect(startNode) + collect(endNode) AS limitedNodes, limitedRels
RETURN { nodes: limitedNodes, relationships: limitedRels
}
```

It collects relationships, limits them and afterwards collects all of the nodes that are either start node or the end node of limited relationships. You can also add `DISTINCT` clause to ensure not having duplicates